# Calculate intersection over union (Jaccard's index) in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, scikit-learn

I have a dataframe like:

```
animal    ids
cat       1,3,4
dog       1,2,4
hamster   5        
dolphin   3,5
```

The dataframe is quite big, with over 80 thousand rows, and ids column may contain easily over thousands, even 10 thousands comma separated id. Ids in a given row would be unique in the comma separated string.

I would like to construct a dataframe which calculated Jaccard's index, i.e. intersection of each items in animal column with each other in ids column over union.

So if we look at cat and dog, the union is 2 (ids 1 and 4), and union is 4 (ids 1, 2, 3, 4), hence the Jaccard's index is 2/4 = 0.5. It would be great to have the dataset in this format:

```
            cat        dog        hamster    dolphin
cat         1          0.5        0          0.25
dog         0.5        1          0          0
hamster     0          0          1          0.5
dolphin     0.25       0          0.5        1
```

which means using the row index as the name of the animal, so that I can find related jaccard's index quickly like:

```
cat_dog_ji = df_new['cat']['dog']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `str.get_dummies` and some `scipy` tools here.

---

```
from scipy.spatial import distance

u = df["ids"].str.get_dummies(",")
j = distance.pdist(u, "jaccard")
k = df["animal"].to_numpy()
pd.DataFrame(1 - distance.squareform(j), index=k, columns=k)
```

---

```
          cat  dog  hamster  dolphin
cat      1.00  0.5      0.0     0.25
dog      0.50  1.0      0.0     0.00
hamster  0.00  0.0      1.0     0.50
dolphin  0.25  0.0      0.5     1.00
```

Comment: Neat use of `scipy`! Using `scipy.distance` here is better in terms of performance.  I'm thinking of deleting my answer ;) +1..

Comment: I think on `80000` rows the initial memory required to allocate the matrix `j` should be very large, right?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, appreciate it. Just one thing though, when I run it with my dataset, I get MemoryError: Unable to allocate 555. GiB for an array with shape (58363, 1277024) and data type int64
Can I use int8 instead of int64, maybe that would help for the memory? How can I do that?

Comment: it gives the MemoryError in the first statement:
u = df["id"].str.get_dummies(",")

Comment: For your memory error, start by encoding the category names into integers. This will save a bit in the process, don't know if enough.

Comment: And to use int8 - it's the default in version 1.1, but since 0.23.4 you can specify dtype in get_dummies: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html

Comment: A little bit more of an explanation would be good here. I'm not familiar with many of the functions used.

Answer (score 3):

**Use:**

```
d = df.assign(key=1, ids=df['ids'].str.split(','))
d = d.merge(d, on='key', suffixes=['', '_r'])

i = [np.intersect1d(*x).size / np.union1d(*x).size for x in zip(d['ids'], d['ids_r'])]
d = pd.crosstab(d['animal'], d['animal_r'], i, aggfunc='first').rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
```

**Details:**

Use [`DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to create a temporary column `key` and use [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) on column `ids`. Then use [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to merge the dataframe `d` with itself based column `key` (essentially a cross join).

```
print(d)

     animal        ids  key animal_r      ids_r
0       cat  [1, 3, 4]    1      cat  [1, 3, 4]
1       cat  [1, 3, 4]    1      dog  [1, 2, 4]
2       cat  [1, 3, 4]    1  hamster        [5]
3       cat  [1, 3, 4]    1  dolphin     [3, 5]
4       dog  [1, 2, 4]    1      cat  [1, 3, 4]
5       dog  [1, 2, 4]    1      dog  [1, 2, 4]
6       dog  [1, 2, 4]    1  hamster        [5]
7       dog  [1, 2, 4]    1  dolphin     [3, 5]
8   hamster        [5]    1      cat  [1, 3, 4]
9   hamster        [5]    1      dog  [1, 2, 4]
10  hamster        [5]    1  hamster        [5]
11  hamster        [5]    1  dolphin     [3, 5]
12  dolphin     [3, 5]    1      cat  [1, 3, 4]
13  dolphin     [3, 5]    1      dog  [1, 2, 4]
14  dolphin     [3, 5]    1  hamster        [5]
15  dolphin     [3, 5]    1  dolphin     [3, 5]
```

Using [`np.interset1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html) along with [`np.union1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.union1d.html) inside list comprehension to calculate the `Jaccard's` index.

```
print(i)
[1.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.25, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0]
```

Finally we use [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) to create a simple cross tabulation to get the result in desired format:

```
print(d)
          cat  dog  dolphin  hamster
cat      1.00  0.5     0.25      0.0
dog      0.50  1.0     0.00      0.0
dolphin  0.25  0.0     1.00      0.5
hamster  0.00  0.0     0.50      1.0
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, appreciate it. When I try to run 
d = d.merge(d, on='key', suffixes=['', '_r'])
kernel crashes and restarts in notebook, probably it's related to the size of the dataset I have, any idea?

Comment: @AhmetCetin yes Ahmet your are right, its due to the size of dataset..